# How to use Eigen library for Arduino within Atmel Studio 7?

Tags: c++, arduino, eigen, arduino-uno, atmelstudio

1. I tried to use Eigen library within the Arduino IDE fist. Then I got the error:

> fatal error: eigenfolder/Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory

2. Then I tried to use EigenArduino library. Then I got an error

> fatal error  cstddef  No such file or directory #include cstddef

So I realized that there is probably a lot of standard library that is not linked/implemented into this Arduino IDE. So before getting everythin I decided to move into ATMEL STUDIO 7. My hope was that Atmel Studio gets everything automatically.

3. But in order to use my previous Arduino Sketches, I also installed Visual Micro that is a Plug-In for Atmel Studio so that you can use everything like in the Arduino IDE.

==> So the problem starts all over again. Same errors in Atmel Studio 7. It seems like I am just using the Atmel Studio 7 Editor now, but the same compiler settings, libraries etc. (Since I am a newbie :-) this is just a guess ).

How can I link all this together? Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the library ?
Did you use libraries manager in Arduino IDE ?
Or you downloaded the library separately ?
I found out that using libraries manager solve most compatibility issues.